# Some users are not present in the "on-premise" database after creation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mesibo

we are using Mesibo "on-premise" to manage a real time chat application but there's a problem registering users on the platform.

We are doing this using the *User Creation Request* documented on [this page](https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/create-users/#create-users-and-access-tokens) and, as expected, we obtain user's id and authtoken.

Nevertheless we can't event start a chat with this user and its status is always "Not Connected".

We dig up in the on-premise database we have in our Docker container and the users are not present there even if they are listed in the Mesibo console as well.

Could you please give us some information bout this process? Should I patch the Mesibo On-Premise DB with the informations? Why it isn't documented anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the mesibo cloud platform for your apps or directly starting with on-premise? If not, follow get started guide and start with cloud first

Comment: Hi, we started with the on-premise one as it's a project requirement. Some users are working correctly, others were not replicated in the users database and so it's impossible for them to be sent messages or added to groups.

Comment: I am trying to help but your answers are vague. On-premise should be only attempted after your project using cloud works fine. I will not be answering further questions, contact mesibo support.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I think my answer was clear. We started with the cloud version and it was working fine. Following the documentation we activated the on-premise version and it's working fine except for this problem.

Comment: Well, as I can read the above comment of yours, you said this "we started with the on-premise one as it's a project requirement." above. Coming back to your question, If your cloud works, and you have setup on-premise correctly, it's just a matter of switching. You should provide more details to support including your APP, user, logs, what exactly is not working instead of vaguely stating some users are work some are not.